# how to use circuit breaker and caching in microservice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, microservices, resilience4j

I'm working on a micro service where I have to aggregate data from multiple apis and expose them as a single api output.I'm using spring boot and I want to use circuit breaker like Resilience4j and Redis caching. is it possible to use them together ? if yes then what should be the approach ? an example would be great.